# Unable to match pattern from JSON output

Tags: bash, sed, grep

My bash script is parsing the JSON output of a build job and trying to find its status by extracting the string `result`, which has three options/values:

- `FAILURE`, if it's a failed build
- `SUCCESS`, succesful build
- `null`, if the build is ongoing

I'm able to extract the `FAILURE` and `SUCCESS` scenario by the command below:

```
val1=`curl -k -s $MY_URL ` 
output=`echo $val1 | sed -e 's/^.*"result":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'`
```

but I'm unable to extract the value `null` with the above commands as it's not enclosed within double quotes.

On-going JSON output:

```
"keepLog":false,"number":10,"result":null,"timestamp":1456785876,
```

Completed build JSON output looks like below:

```
"keepLog":false,"number":10,"result":"FAILURE","timestamp":1456785876,
```

Any inputs on how to ignore the double quotes while matching the pattern and to extract only the string (`null` or `FAILURE` or `SUCCESS`)?

Comment: Any particular reason to use `sed` here and not a command-line JSON query tool built for the job? `jq`, for instance, bills itself as being ["like `sed` for JSON data"](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: @JeffBowman : jq utility is not available on my build server and no permission to install , so have to choose any of the available default utility like sed or grep ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple groups in your regular expression like so:

```
echo $'..."result":null...\n..."result":"FAILURE"...' | \
sed -e 's/^.*"result":\("\([^"]*\)"\|\(null\)\).*$/\2\3/'
```

The above example outputs

```
null
FAILURE
```

The expression either matches the first (quoted) or the second (null) alternative (`\|`), never both. The corresponding groups are the `\2` and `\3`.

Answer (score 1):

If your grep **supports Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE)**, you can use this command:

```
grep -Po '"result":"?\K[^",]*(?="?,)' infile
```

where the contents of `infile` are

```
"keepLog":false,"number":10,"result":null,"timestamp":1456785876,
"keepLog":false,"number":10,"result":"FAILURE","timestamp":1456785876,
```

- `-o` retains only the matched part
- `"result":"?\K` matches the part before the `\K`, but doesn't include it in the match ("variable-length positive look-behind")

  - `"?` is an optional `"`, so both `"result":"` and `"result":` match
- `[^",]*` matches any number of characters that are *not* either `"` or `,`
- `(?="?,)` is a positive look-ahead, i.e., the match must be followed by the pattern `"?,`: an optional `"` followed by a comma

If your grep **does *not* support PCRE**, you can use two commands like this (same input file):

```
grep -Eo '"result":"?[^",]*' infile | grep -o '[^":]*$'
```

- `-E` is for extended regular expressions so we can use the `?` modifier
- `-o` is the same as above
- `"result":"?[^",]*` matches both `"result":` and `"result":"` followed by any number of characters other than `"` or `,` – the output of the first command looks like this:

  ```
  "result":null
  "result":"FAILURE
  ```
- In the second command, `[^":]*$` matches any number of characters other than `"` or `:` at the end of the string, resulting in

  ```
  null
  FAILURE
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
$ cat file
"keepLog":false,"number":10,"result":null,"timestamp":1456785876,
"keepLog":false,"number":10,"result":"FAILURE","timestamp":1456785876,

$ awk -F'[:",]+' '{print $7}' file
null
FAILURE
```

or if there's more in your log file than you've shown us and you need to only find the "result" lines:

```
$ awk -F'[:",]+' '$6=="result"{print $7}' file
null
FAILURE
```

If that's not what you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.